# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I am getting this error and do not know how to solve it:

```
  var directions = LocationService().getDirections(
                  _originController.text, _destinationController.text);
             _goToPlace(directions['start_location']['lat'], directions['start_location']['lng']);
             setPolyline(directions['polyline_decoded']);
            },
```

Below is the code of the _goToPlace() method:

```
Future<void> _goToPlace(double lat, double lng) async {

    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controllerGoogleMap.future;
    controller.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(lat, lng),
          zoom: 12,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark your function as async and put an await before your getDirections

```
await LocationService().getDirections(
                  _originController.text, _destinationController.text);
```

Your getDirections returns a Future, so you have await it.